# Passing a value to a variable in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scripting

I am writing a script that will do the following:

1. remove a specific directory
2. set a encrypted password as a variable
3. use the encrypet password tin a command to decrypt it
4. set the decrypted password as a variable
5. use the decrypted password in a command to start a service

This is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf <folder path>

VAR_1="<encrypted>"
VAR_2=""

# runs the decryption command
java -jar <path to file> -d $VAR_1

# runs service script
cd <path>
./<path to file> $VAR_2

# end of script
echo "all done"
```

So the folder removal is correct. The `crypto` command works but I am having trouble with the syntax to pass the decrypted password into the 2nd variable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out. I set java command to output to a txt file, then use the text file in VAR_2. It works now.